# Paste an entire sheet instead of a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs an anti-filter concept and pastes the results into a sheet called "AF".

How can I adjust this so instead of pasting Column T from "CurrentList" it pastes columns A:Q.  I tried tweaking some of the variables.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub XC()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("CurrentList")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Range("S1").Resize(LastRow)
    
    Dim Lookup As Variant
    Lookup = rng.Value
    
    Set rng = src.Range("T1").Resize(LastRow)
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    Result = rng.Value
    
    Dim LookupValue As Variant
                                   
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MatchCount As Long
       
    For i = 1 To UBound(Lookup)
     
        LookupValue = Lookup(i, 1)
    
        If Not IsError(LookupValue) Then
            If LookupValue = "Yes" Then
                MatchCount = MatchCount + 1
                Result(MatchCount, 1) = Result(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    
    Next i
    
    If MatchCount = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets("AF")
    
    Set rng = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Set rng = rng.Resize(MatchCount)
    
    rng.Value = Result
    
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just change your reference from T to A:Q? Btw probably quicker to use autofilter and avoid a loop.

Comment: I tried modifying the line  Set rng = src.Range("T1").Resize(LastRow)   to A:Q and it did not work, just pastes a single value seemingly off of the wrong column.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't keep re-using variable names, it gets rather confusing. Your current code looks at column T so what should it be doing instead? Is it supposed to check each column from A to Q?

Comment: So basically if Column S in "CurrentList" sheet = "Yes" , I want to paste that entire row to the AF Sheet.   Currently, it just pastes column T, but I actually need the full sheet.   My one requirement would be that column T (which is the same column exact value as column T would be column A in the "AF" sheet, but I can do that in a later step if needed.

Comment: Then your output array needs to be more than 1 column and you need to populate each column. As I say though autofilter probably simpler.

Comment: Alright , so is it these lines that need to change?  not sure how to format properly in msg here but:      For i = 1 To UBound(Lookup)

        LookupValue = Lookup(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(LookupValue) Then

            If LookupValue = "Yes" Then

                MatchCount = MatchCount + 1

                Result(MatchCount, 1) = Result(i, 1)

Comment: Your re-use of `rng` has confused me. What is the significance of column T? Anyway you need to dimension `Result` so 2nd dimension is number of columns A:Q and then add `Result(MatchCount, 2)=...` etc.

Comment: Why don't you just use autofilter and avoid the loop?

Comment: Not sure how to write the syntax for the autofilter solution you outline.  Column T I think is making this too complex, so just ignore column T for now..  It's really just pasting/appending every row that column S from sheet "CurrentList" has with "Yes" to sheet AF.    The key thing is there is a running list in sheet AF so it's important that the paste is an append.  I thought of just doing recorded macro , but that won't account for the append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. You'll have to adjust sheet names.

```
Sub x()

Dim rData As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("CurrentList")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:="Yes"
    With .AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rData Is Nothing Then
            Intersect(rData, .Range("A:Q")).Copy Worksheets("AF").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```